# Link inside android webview is opened twice

Tags: php, android, html, mysql, android-webview

I'm having a weird problem with android's webview. I load a page to the webview which has a link in it. I have set the webview to open that link in the same webview (not on a browser). When the next page is opened it writes some stuff to mysql. If an user has already opened that second page on a same day, the user gets redirected to the first page and no stuff is written to mysql. I noticed that in 1 out of 3-4 times on first situation pressing the link writes the stuff to mysql twice (with a same timestamp) and redirects the user right away to first page. So it seems that when the link is clicked the url is opened twice in a row. Everything works as supposed on my computer's browsers (safari, firefox and chrome). I found some article that said that empty src-fields on images can cause this but there are no empty src-fields in my php/html code.

Webview is set like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_description);

        WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient()
        {

            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/404.html");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String  url)
            {
             if ( url.contains("google") == false ) {                   
                 webView.loadUrl(url);
                 return false;
             }
             else {
                 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                 startActivity(i);
                 return true;
             }               
            }
        };

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        String url = (MainActivity.URL+"app/description.php?tagid="+tagId+"&screenwidth="+viewPortWidth+"&screenheight="+viewPortHeight+"&deviceid="+MainActivity.myDeviceId+"&lang="+MainActivity.myLanguage+"&os=android);

        webView.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

My link is just a typical div inside an anchor tag (written in php):

```
echo '<a href="description.php?type='.$type.'&screenwidth='.$screenWidth.'&screenheight='.$screenHeight.'&tagid='.$tagid.'&no=1&deviceid='.$deviceid.'&lang='.$language.'">
<div class="redbutton">'.$lang['NO'].'</div></a>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually only return false, webpage will automatically be loaded in `WebView`. No need to use `webView.loadUrl();`.

```
if ( url.contains("google") == false ) {                   
                 return false;
             }
```

Give it a try and let me know if doesn't work.

As [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) states -

> while return false means the current WebView handles the url

Comment: Tested this and it seems to be working. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: if this is the right one. You may mark it correct answer to help future programmers who stumble upon same question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the reason for this. This was the cause:

```
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String  url)
        {

            if ( url.contains("google") == false ) {

             webView.loadUrl(url);
             return false; // <----THIS LINE
         }
         else {
             Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
             startActivity(i);
             return false;
         }               
        }
```

That should have returned true. I found this out by testing with this:

```
@Override           
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                String url_new = view.getUrl();                

                Log.v("","Webview url: "+url_new);

            }
```

I noticed that it printed out the url twice every time that some link was pressed, but it didn't do that when the webview was loaded first time. When I changed the return statement to true it only printed out once per click as it's supposed to do.

Comment: `Return  false` was right thing to do. You need to understand the reason behind how it works this way. Find my answer below.`